# Heine–Borel theorem: why is the condition closed and bounded?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

The Heine–Borel theorem says:

> A subset of $\mathbb R^k$ is compact if it is closed **and** bounded.

At the same when I think that any either closed or bounded is enough: if it is bounded it must be a subset of a $k$-cell and thus compact. If it is closed, every subsequence converges to the limit that lies in it and hence compact.

So, why don't they say a set is compact if either it is closed **or** bounded?

Comment: "Because if it is bounded it must be a subset of a k-cell and compact." No, not at all. This is not true. The bounded interval $(-1,1)$ is **NOT** compact.

Answer (score 4):

There are closed sets that are not bounded, for example $\{ x : x \ge 0 \}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and there are bounded subsets that are not closed, for example $\{ x : -1 < x < 1 \}$, again as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.